# JQuery datepicker not outputting values to gridview

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, datepicker

I have a JQuery Datepicker bound correctly (I feel so) to the gridview. It works fine and shows perfectly on all textboxes of the grid and on each row.

The problem is that it outputs the value to only first row.

So when I click on 10th row of the grid, a DatePicker pops out on the 10th Row, but when I select a date, that date is filled in the first row of the grid only.

No matter which row I choose, it always outputs the value to first row only.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried to attach the DatePicker through both textbox ID as well as the Class name with no luck.

Thanks
Ashutosh

```
    $("#txtGivenDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy", max: '0', changeYear: true,         changeMonth: true });
```

And the grid markup is as below:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Given Date" ControlStyle-Width="90%" HeaderStyle-Width="9%">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtGivenDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("GivenDate")%>' BorderStyle="None"
                        CssClass="youpi"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Tried all possible solutions

1. Using Class name instead of ID
2. Using IDs  to identify the name of the textbox
3. Using ClientIDMode=Static in the textbox declaration
4. Attaching the JS from code behind on the RowCreated event of the gridview.

None seemed to work.

Thanks
Ashutosh

Comment: How are you doing it.Provide your aspx markup code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out the answer.

Problem was with the ClientIDMode.

We need to set ClientIDMode of the textbox to "AutoID".

Setting this worked well and problem was resolved.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you append the `$('#'+yourControl.ClientID).datepicker(...);` initializer to a StringBuilder in the GridView's `RowDataBound` event, then register the StringBuilder as a startup script after all the rows have been data bound, in the grid's `DataBound` event.

**EDIT:** You could also try using the class name. Eg: `$('.youpi').datepicker();`

Comment: Tried both as my edit about shows. Could not get the desired results.